# Python remove duplicates in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, unique

My dictionary looks something like this:

```
dictionary= {apple:[3,5], banana:[3,3,6], strawberry:[1,2,4,5,5]}
```

How am I able to remove all duplicates (so create a set) for each value/list?

I would like the new dictionary to be look this:

```
{apple:[3,5], banana:[3,6], strawberry:[1,2,4,5]}
```

Comment: If you're familiar with sets, what's the problem? Maybe post an attempt?

Comment: That's not valid code. Add quotes.

Comment: Are your lists always ordered? In either case do you need to preserve the order of their remaining elements? Are the elements hashable?

Answer (score 5):

using dict comprehension and sets to remove duplicates

```
d= {'apple':[3,5], 'banana':[3,3,6], 'strawberry':[1,2,4,5,5]}
print {k:list(set(j)) for k,j in d.items()}
```

results in

```
{'strawberry': [1, 2, 4, 5], 'apple': [3, 5], 'banana': [3, 6]}
```

If you want to preserve the list order

```
d= {'apple':[3,5,5,8,4,5], 'banana':[3,3,6,1,1,3], 'strawberry':[5,1,1,2,4,5,5]}
print {k:sorted(set(j),key=j.index) for k,j in d.items()}
```

results in:

```
{'strawberry': [5, 1, 2, 4], 'apple': [3, 5, 8, 4], 'banana': [3, 6, 1]}
```

Comment: @J. Williams If you like this answer. Can you please accept it

Answer (score 2):

```
for lst in dictionary.values():
    lst[:] = list(set(lst))
```

Going through `set` might change the order, though. If that must not happen, `OrderedDict` is an option:

```
for lst in dictionary.values():
    lst[:] = list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))
```

Or if the lists shall be sorted, you can do that instead:

```
for lst in dictionary.values():
    lst[:] = sorted(set(lst))
```

Or if the lists already are sorted, you could keep the first element and every element that's not a duplicate of the element before it.

```
for lst in dictionary.values():
    lst[:] = lst[:1] + [b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if a != b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dictionary= {"apple":[3,5], "banana":[3,3,6], "strawberry":[1,2,4,5,5]}
 for key,item in dictionary.items():
     dictionary[key]=set(item)

 print(dictionary)
```

output:

```
 {'apple': {3, 5}, 'banana': {3, 6}, 'strawberry': {1, 2, 4, 5}}
```